# serialize only selects multiples with some options selected

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

i have 4 selects multiples, and i want to serialize and send only the fields with some options selected, because, with all options are selected i dont need to send to make a "column in ('bla,bla,bla')" in my query.

I relied in this test

```
$("#myForm :input[value!=''][value!='.']").serialize();
```

and this test

```
$("#myForm option:not(:selected)").length == 0;
```

and i try some things like this

```
$("#mapasFiltro option:not(:selected).length > 0").serialize();
```

but i can not do something functional

Comment: jQuery only serializes  "successful controls". For selects it would be: _Only selected options may be successful. When no options are selected, the control is not successful and neither the name nor any values are submitted to the server when the form is submitted._

Comment: it does not help me. If all options are selected I do not want to send them to submit, because if I filter the query for all options or filter nothing, the return will be the same, so I want to escape this where in the query when all are selected for not encumber the server.